# ListView's item with clickable link is not clickable

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, listviewitem

Why item is not clickable when it contains web links(android:autoLink="web"). How to make so that worked and links, and selects an item in the list? I tried to set the property in the root element **"android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"**, but it did not help When i clicked **1** item is not selected, just open link. When i clicked **2** item is selected. Thx. Please sorry for my English
[image]
**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="3dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/items_selector"
        android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="2dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/messageText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:autoLink="web"
            android:padding="@dimen/layout_margin"
            android:text="Сообщение"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#F5F5F5"
            android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/info"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/userNick"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:text="goest"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/messageDate"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/userNick"
                    android:text="57 мин. назад"
                    android:textSize="12sp"/>
            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ratingLayout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/info"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/like"
                    android:layout_width="12dp"
                    android:layout_height="12dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/like"
                    android:clickable="true"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/likeCount"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:textSize="12sp"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/dislike"
                    android:layout_width="12dp"
                    android:layout_height="12dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/dislike"
                    android:clickable="true"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/dislikeCount"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="12sp"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: if you are using textview in layout use Text1.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

Comment: When i added setMovementMethod list item become is not selectable when click it

Comment: Not works. :( When i added this, item become is not focusable and not selectable. But links is opened.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible solutions. First of all, you could use autoLink flag in TextView:

```
android:autoLink="web"
```

The other way is to use setMovementMethod on TextView programatically:

```
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

I hope it works for you.

Comment: Not. When i added android:autoLink="web" item is not selectable.

Comment: It depends on how your links are created. If you get HTML with <a href> tags already insered it won't help. setMovementMethod() should help tho...

Comment: Please look at the new screenshots and descriptions to understand what I want.